I would like to add swap space on my system running TrueNAS
First my hardware:

Gigabyte H55M-D2H
I5-650
2X4GB DDR3
GTX1030
128GB SSD
8TB HDD, RAIDZ1 (RAID5) usable 5.5TB

I would like to somehow increase to 16GB or 32GB RAM, however my motherboard only supports up to 8GB.
I would like to know if there is any way I could set up swap storage on my SSD in TrueNAS scale. I am also looking at upgrading to i7-860 soon, if that might increase the max RAM that would work as well.
Ideally I wouldn't upgrade motherboard but if I have to then I will.

Update: The problem I am trying to solve is my VMs crashing due to not having enough memory. I am hoping by adding swap space the system will prioritize my VMs over other functions and move them to the swap space.

Please don't change your question substantially. Swap space cannot support VMs.

If the motherboard has a stated limit of RAM, then bypassing that is most likely "impossible" unless you have inside information from the motherboard producer.
The same is true for a CPU upgrade too.
A new motherboard is required for either of them.

So even if i can add a swap partition to my SSD I can't go over my motherboard's stated memory max? i seem to remember LTT setting up 2TB of swap storage at some point.

Swap helps with the merory operation but it's NOT additional memory. It won't help with anything you think you need more RAM to and that you need more than you have already for TrueNAS is highly debatable. Perhaps a better idea is to ask about the actual problem you're trying to solve, if any, instead of you think is a solution.

@ChanganAuto I agree my question was not very well written. i suppose what i am actually asking is: how can i add swap space to my truenas server. i want to do this so the zfs cache can fill up the swap space rather than the actual RAM allowing my VMs to run without crashing.

TruNAS is very well documented. What research have you done? Managing swap is trivial like in any other Linux distro. That however is very unlikely to be be cause of whatever unnamed VMs are crashing. The fact is running VMs in TruNAS is quite experimental, you have a very old hardware likely not up to the task (yet perfectly fine for TrueNAS). As expected this is a X-Y problem.
